# Cannot send iMessage from MacBook Pro

Tags: messages, facetime

I have been using my MacBook Pro for nearly 2 years. I have no problem using iMessages both on my iPhone and Mac. However, today, I can't seem to be able to send any messages out from my Mac. There is no problem on my phone. Also, I cannot use FaceTime on my Mac.

I reviewed through the internet for some solutions, but nothing seems to work, such as deleting files, changing setting on the Flash Player.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Have tried disabling imessage and enabling it again?

Comment: How do I disable and enable it on my mac? I tried logging off and signing back on but still no change.

Comment: Messages>Preferences>[yourAccount]>Enable this account Uncheck this. Facetime>Preferences>Turn OFF the switch

Comment: Yes, tried that and it does not work still.

Comment: Does the program show you any error messages?

Answer (score -2):

It has something to do with not having a serial number on your Mac (after motherboard repair or so). You need to go to an Apple Store to have it “flashed” back. iMessage and FaceTime won't work without the serial.

Comment: I did not send my lap top for any repairs. All I did was upgrade to OSX Mavericks. It was working for 2 days and suddenly it could not work yesterday. Will this also result in the missing serial number on my Mac?

Comment: This is not about a serial number. iMessages often times gets confused. Try removing the accounts and re-adding them.